# is there an active verb for what a "thing being consumed" does?

Tags: antonyms

if we consider the sentence `birds consume spiders, and spiders consume flies`

the "opposite" of that sentence is something like `is flies <> spiders and spiders <> birds` but, more active. As if the spider jumps down the birds throat.

I'm looking for that word. Something similar to "feeds into", but just one word ideally.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/consume was not much help, I'm considering it in the second or third context, but from the point of view of the thing being consumed

Comment: _Feed_ itself is possible, though hardly conventional. _Flies feed spiders, and spiders feed birds_.

Comment: *Nourish* would be another possible verb. (As would *sustain* and *energize*.) Although less specific than *feed*, it seems more conventional to me.

Comment: Why does the obvious "feed" not work for you? "Flies feed spiders and spiders feed birds…"

Comment: Wriggling flies sate the spiders; web-plucked spiders nutrify the birds.

Comment: I think the problem with finding an active word is that spiders *don't* in general jump down birds' throats. The transformation into food is something almost invariably *done to* a creature, so it will be hard to find an active word that doesn't convey a strongly ironic or comedic tone, or in which there isn't a strong tendency to interpret the creature as an agent for the delivery of food as opposed to the creature's body being the food itself.

Answer (score 1):

The word [***nourish***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nourish) is occasionally used this way, though usually for inanimate (or at least no-longer-animate) substances. From Merriam-Webster

> 3. a. : to furnish or sustain with nutriment : <sub><sup>FEED</sup></sub> *Plants are nourished by rain and soil*.

A couple of examples of this usage:

> This hypoallergenic kibble **nourishes** your cat
>   —["James Wellbeloved Adult Cat Housecat - Duck" cat food ad](https://www.bitiba.co.uk/shop/cats/dry_cat_food/wellbeloved_catfood/wellbeloved_cat_adult/359831)
>
> Research has shown that donated breast milk can nourish babies just as well as mother's own milk can.
>   —[Heidi Murkoff and Sharon Mazel, *What to Expect the First Year*, 2014.](https://books.google.com/books?id=YHzEAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA93&ots=bzqdDzotnz&dq=%22milk%20can%20nourish%22&pg=PA93#v=onepage&q=%22milk%20can%20nourish%22&f=false)

In your case, you could say

> Flies **nourish** spiders and spiders **nourish** birds.

The primary problem with this term (and also *feed*, as suggested in the comments and in M-W's definition for *nourish*) is that with animate subjects it is usually used to mean that the subject provides (some other) nourishment to the object: I nourish my children with healthy meals, nourish their imaginations with plenty of playtime, and nourish my skin with rich creams and lotions (that last one is probably debatable, science-wise). So readers may get a mental image of spiders bringing birdseed to birds, rather than crawling into the birds' mouths.

Even with this caveat, I think this is probably the best you can do, since offering oneself up to be eaten is a rare enough activity that there's not much call for an everyday verb to describe the action.

Comment: Just realized @JasonBassford also suggested this in a comment, as I was taking my sweet time to answer (or rather, working in an answer around paid activities...). So hat-tip to Jason!

Answer (score 0):

How about the phrase, "is/are consumed by"?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to EL&U. Please expand on your answer. Stack Exchange answers should be more than suggestions - they are expected to be authoritative. Links to examples of usage would help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for that word. Something similar to "feeds into", but just one word ideally. Either 'refuel' or 'replenish?'

[www.healthline.com](http://www.healthline.com) › health › post-workout-foods-hiit(*sic*)
The bottom line. '**Refueling** your body with nutritious, whole foods after HIIT is essential to ...'

Alternatively, replenish:to make full or complete again, as by supplying what is lacking, used up, etc.: to replenish one's stock of food. **to supply** (a fire, stove, etc.) with fresh fuel. to fill again or anew.

The fly refuelled the spider which, in turn, refuelled the bird.

The fly replenished the spider which, in turn, replenished the bird.

Answer (score -3):

**prey**:

an animal hunted or seized for food, especially by a carnivorous animal

It can be used as a verb. For instance:

> Birds **preying** on spiders is quite a sight!

Comment: Birds prey on spiders, spiders don't prey (on/in) birds. The question is looking for the opposite relation to eating, not a word describing the same relationship.